# automatically generate document title from string list with Python

Tags: python, list, title

I am trying to organize news according to channels, i.e, I need to use the elements in list_a (below) to name my txt file, then write corresponding strings of the same channel into same document.
These txt files can be written to my current fold, no hassle about this

My current concern is how to write it efficiently. Since I don't know how many strings would be written into the document, the current document needs to hold on until string exhausted and new document kicks in.

The following is an example:

Input:  2 string lists:

```
list_a=['abc','abc','fox','abc',....]

list_b=['campus shooting', 'Congress sucks', 'debt ceiling','1% rich', ...]
```

Output: 
2 documents with title 'abc.txt' and 'fox.txt' respectively

In document abc.txt

```
campus shooting

congress sucks
```

In document fox.txt

```
debt ceiling
```

Comment: So, the lists are always ordered that way? [chanX, chanY, chanZ] and [new_from_chan_x, new_from_chan_y, new_from_chan_z]?, if so, you can acomplish that with a zip()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `zip()` here and open files in append mode( `'a'`) :

```
In [44]: list_a=['abc','abc','fox','abc']
In [45]: list_b=['campus shooting', 'Congress sucks', 'debt ceiling','1% rich']

In [46]: for x,y in zip(list_a,list_b):
   ....:     with open(x+".txt" , "a") as f:
   ....:         f.write(y+'\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method that opens files only once:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_a = ['abc', 'abc', 'fox', 'abc']
list_b = ['campus shooting', 'Congress sucks', 'debt ceiling','1% rich']

results = defaultdict(list)

for title, text in zip(list_a, list_b):
    results[title].append(text)

for title, result in results.iteritems():
    with open("%s.txt" % title , "w") as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

Opening a file for each item might be expensive (don't guess, compare performance with this version that avoids it):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

L = sorted(zip(list_a, list_b), key=itemgetter(0)) # sorted (a, b) pairs
for name, group in groupby(L, key=itemgetter(0)):
    with open(name + ".txt", "w") as file:
        for a, b in group:
            file.write(b + "\n")
```

Comment: `sort()` is guaranteed to be stable since Python 2.2 i.e., the items with the same title should preserve order.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: you are right. I forgot to add key to sorted() to preserve order. Fixed.